# SSH in to MAMP with terminal error

Tags: terminal, mamp

I am trying to SSH in to the MAMP htdoc directory to compile a file, but it keeps saying `'connection refused'`. I am using this command:

```
ssh -p 80 johnpett@**.**.***.***

ssh -p 22 johnpett@**.**.***.***

ssh -p 8888 johnpett@**.**.***.***
```

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Check your remote machine Iptables and make sure that ssh port is open or scan your remote machine port using nmap

```
nmap <remote_machine_ip>
```

In your remote machine, your public ip must not present in the below file

```
cat /etc/hosts.deny | grep <your_public_address>
```

In your remote machine, check SSH is listening on custom port no

```
netstat -plnat
```

Also check the SSH configuration file in the remote machine which allows the user "johnpett"

See here : http://linuxinternetworks.com/how-to-login-into-linux-server-or-client-using-ssh/

Comment: Thanks Sathish, but it seems doing this on a local MAMP setup doesn't work the same as normal Linux server behaviour. Or am I missing a trick!?